# SuHosin configuration for Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

My web hosting provider decided to use the [suhosin](http://www.dynamiteheads.com/blog/jakub-suchy/drupal-security-using-suhosin-secure-php-installations) php extension to protect my websites.

For some Drupal 7 sites, I am now getting tons of errors and can't login:

```
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in drupal_environment_initialize() (line 675 of /home/reseller1/example.com/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in drupal_environment_initialize() (line 678 of /home/reseller1/example.com/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in drupal_environment_initialize() (line 679 of /home/reseller1/example.com/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in drupal_environment_initialize() (line 680 of /home/reseller1/example.com/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in drupal_environment_initialize() (line 682 of /home/reseller1/example.com/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in drupal_environment_initialize() (line 684 of /home/reseller1/example.com/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in include_once() (line 300 of /home/reseller1/example.com/sites/default/settings.php).
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in include_once() (line 301 of /home/reseller1/example.com/sites/default/settings.php).
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in include_once() (line 309 of /home/reseller1/example.com/sites/default/settings.php).
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in include_once() (line 316 of /home/reseller1/example.com/sites/default/settings.php).
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in drupal_settings_initialize() (line 772 of /home/reseller1/example.com/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

Is there an alternative bootstrap without those ini_set statements? 
Can we put them on Drupal?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could try and override the setting in a local

[php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)

file.

For example.

*/var/www/my-site/php.ini*

```
disable_functions = system
```

Adding a single function instead of the list your host is using by default.

If that works, you could add other functions there, e.g

```
disable_functions = exec,shell_exec,popen,passthru,proc_open,system,pcntl_exec
```

Otherwise, you'll need to hack Drupal to remove those ini_set declarations and move them to the local php.ini file. ( not recommended )

You could also ask your webhost for help ( recommended )

Alternatively, find a new webhost.